# FileNotFoundError with no-extension file in python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-os

i have a no-extension file in path: C:/Users/example/Downloads.
the file name is examplefile, so path will be C:/Users/example/Downloads/examplefile.
i tried to use

`os.stat("C:/Users/example/Downloads/examplefile").st_size`

but i got this error:

```
  File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in <module>
    os.stat(file).st_size
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The specified file could not be found: 'C:/Users/example/Downloads/examplefile'
```

so i tried using `os.path.getsize()` but i still got the same error.
How can i get file size?

Comment: Chances are the file actually has an extension, and the visualization you have of it on your OS is hidding it. Just find the complete file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file does *have* an extension in this case - it is just windows that does not show it in the default configurations.

You can gt the real file name from Python by using a glob-pattern when trying to get to it.

As a convenience, you might want to use the `pathlib`, instead of `os` , as it will combine glob functionality and stat in a single place:

```py
from pathlib import Path

path_to_guess = Path("C:/Users/example/Downloads/examplefile")

path = path_to_guess.parent.glob(path_to_guess.stem + ".*")[0]
print(path)
# here you have the extension. Of course, you might have more than one
# file with the same base name- this is good for a
# one time script or interactive use - 
# for production you should check also creation time, and maybe use
# other means to pick the correct file.
size = path.stat.st_size()
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>You should use \\ instead of / when referring to paths in python.
`os.stat(C:\\Users\\example\\Downloads\\examplefile).st_size` should do the job.</s>

Sorry, forgot that python automatically interprets that and doesn't answer the question. It doesn't give an error when I try to do it your way though:

```
import os
file = "C:/Users/user/Downloads/data"
print(os.stat(file).st_size)
```

Comment: Python translates "/" in filepaths on Windows to the (im)proper `\\` separator automatically. This does not have to do with the issue.

Comment: if you are wondering why \\ and not \ because you have to escape it (\n is a newline character while \\n is only '\n')

Comment: Also, a hint for when you are posting answers: avoid using pseudo code, and when posting an answer, please verify that it is syntactically correct. In this case, you did not quote the filename in the call - it would raise an error.

Comment: @jsbueno, `os.stat` doesn't translate slash to backslash, but the Windows file API itself does when the implementation of `os.stat` calls `CreateFileW` or (rarely, if the latter fails in some cases) `FindFirstFileW` -- unless it's a verbatim path that begins with `"\\\\?\\"`.